# How to call module block after header?

Tags: layout, blocks, xml, magento1.9.2.3

I have a module layout file below

```
<default>
    <block name="ampromo_notification" type="ampromo/notification" template="amasty/ampromo/notification.phtml" before="-" />
    <reference name="content">
        <action ifconfig="ampromo/messages/display_notification" method="append"><block>ampromo_notification</block></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

This file shows the content of the template file at top of the content area at the frontend.

I want to show this file content just after the header block ends.

So how can I move this block to the after header?

I have tried this as well in 2columns-left.phtml, but didn't work

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ampromo_notification'); ?>
```

Currently, the layout files and template files exist in the `base>default` folder, while I am using the theme folder. So can it be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<block name="ampromo_notification" type="ampromo/notification" template="amasty/ampromo/notification.phtml" before="-" />
```

with this

```
<block name="ampromo_notification" type="ampromo/notification" template="amasty/ampromo/notification.phtml" after="header" />
```

Comment: above code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="header">
    <reference name="top.container">
        <block name="ampromo_notification" type="ampromo/notification" template="amasty/ampromo/notification.phtml" after="-" />
    </reference>
</reference>
```

Remove `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ampromo_notification'); ?>`

Comment: using above code, it shows content in header block at the top of page, but I want to show it just after the header ends and just before the content starts.

Comment: Are you sure ? did you clean a cache ?

Comment: Yes.. content is showing at the top of the page now.

Comment: did you removed `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('ampromo_notification'); ?>` in phtml ?

Comment: yes, ofcourse..I did

Comment: where did you put my code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is for after `header`, inside `content`, before all other blocks.

```
<reference name="content">
    <reference name="top.container">
        <block name="ampromo_notification" type="ampromo/notification" template="amasty/ampromo/notification.phtml" before="-" />
    </reference>
</reference>
```

Or within `global_messages` (before content)

```
<reference name="global_messages">
    <reference name="top.container">
        <block name="ampromo_notification" type="ampromo/notification" template="amasty/ampromo/notification.phtml" before="-" />
    </reference>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort you can do stuff like this in template html

```php
echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Chapagain\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld')
          ->setTemplate('Chapagain_HelloWorld::helloworld.phtml')
          ->toHtml();
```

And remove the other XML reference. Whilst I appreciate this isn't the best approach we all have deadlines.